# Build failed with exception error on flutter vscode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

I am trying to run my  flutter application on my android 11 device to reduce the stress on my laptop. It works just fine using an emulator, but it keeps giving an error trying to run on my device. I ran flutter doctor and everything is fine.

The error code

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              7.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

I also ran flutter clean and re installed the files.

kotlin and android level build.gradle

```
buildscript { 
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50' repositories { 
google() 
mavenCentral() 
} 
dependencies { 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' 
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checked kotlin version? That was the problem of my last issue.

Check out your android level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
**ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'**
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have not, how do I do this?

Comment: I edited my comment for you.

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}